# Backup Photos photobook templates

Tags: backup, photos

I want to backup the photobook templates in Photos, because they will be discontinued at the end of the month and I want to continue to use them.

I found a cache here,

```
/Users/user/Library/Containers/com.apple.iPhoto/Data/Library/Application Support/iLifePageLayout/ThemeCache
```

but looks like it's just a cache, I want to have a backup of the files, so when in a few years I need them again, I can restore them.

Comment: "they will be discontinued at the end of the month"? What do you mean?

Comment: @JBis when you open the Photos app and try to create some product, it tells you that this feature will be discontinued at the end of this month, and you need to download some alternative app from the app store (and alternatives are not good)

Comment: Ah. Not sure how to do what your doing but I doubt that the same format would work for third party apps (unless the apps suggested are made by Apple).

Comment: @JBis no, the suggested apps are independent from Photos, they're just opened from Photos and have access to the Photos library. And of course, you can't save as PDF